# Division between the sum of two columns

Tags: sql, aggregate, division

I need to take the sum of two columns and divide the totals.  Both columns are of decimal data type.  Here is what I have so far which does not work.

```
SELECT total_salary / DistEnroll
FROM   dbo.vw_Salary
WHERE  DistEnroll = (
           SELECT DISTINCT(distenroll)
           FROM   dbo.vw_Salary
           WHERE  YEAR = '2012'
                  AND dist_name = 'Sch Dist'
       )
       AND total_salary = (
               SELECT SUM(total_salary)
               FROM   [vw_salary]
               WHERE  YEAR = '2012'
                      AND dist_name = 'Sch Dist'
           )
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
select 
       ( select sum(total_salary) 
        from [vw_salary] 
        where year = '2012'
        and dist_name = 'Sch Dist') --totalsal
       /
       (select count(distinct distenroll) 
        from dbo.vw_Salary
        where year = '2012'
        and dist_name = 'Sch Dist') -- DistEnroll
```

or, better:

```
        select sum(total_salary)  /  count(distinct distenroll) 
        from [vw_salary] 
        where year = '2012' and 
              dist_name = 'Sch Dist'
```

Comment: If I wanted to convert the answer to nvarchar how would I go about doing that?

Comment: @Tone I don't understand. Maybe that would be another question?

Comment: I figured it out - select convert(nvarchar(255), sum(total_salary)  /  sum(distinct distenroll))
        from [vw_salary] 
        where year = 2012
        and dist_name = dist_name 
  and school_name = @school_name